# Plotting multiple subplots with different shapefiles in background

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot side by side GeoPandas shapefiles using matplotlib but the titles, xlabel and ylabel are not plotting correctly.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,3), sharex=True, sharey=True)

base = subs.boundary.plot(color='black', linewidth=0.1, ax=axes[0])
cluster.plot(ax=base, column='pixel', markersize=20, legend=True, zorder=2)
plt.title('THHZ')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')


base = forest.boundary.plot(color='black', linewidth=0.2, ax=axes[1])
cluster.plot(ax=base, column='forest', markersize=20, legend=True, zorder=2)
plt.title('Forest')
```

This is what I get

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because if you do `plt.something` matplotlib always takes the last axes!
So instead of `plt.set_xlabel` do the following:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,3), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1.set_xlabel("asdf")
ax2.set_xlabel("asdf")
...
```

and for the geopandas plots pass the axis as `gdf.plot(ax=ax1, ...)`